# Добавить класс в winforms приложение

Tags: c#, winforms, классы

У меня есть winform приложение клиент-серверные шашки, сейчас речь конкретно про клиента. Всё написано в одной форме, я будучи не знамо как сделать правильно, сделал следующим образом, создал ещё пару форм одна - "CheckresLogic", другая "Chat" потому что в шашках ещё есть чат. Сделал я эти формы partial и теперь у меня всё работает отлично, ну понятное дело всё компилируется в один класс, но ведь это не правильно я полагаю. Подскажите как сделать по уму? Нужно проект library в solution туда положить методы, которые в классах "CheckresLogic" и "Chat" и добавить ссылку на этот library? Но тогда у меня всё поедет, у меня много где используется класс Button, а в library Button'а не будет, как быть подскажите?
Вот основная форма: (не вся)

```
 private delegate void printer(string data);
        private delegate void cleaner();
        printer Printer;
        cleaner Cleaner;
        private Socket _serverSocket;
        private Thread _clientThread;
        private string _serverHost;
        private int _serverPort;
        public ClientForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Printer = new printer(Print);
            Cleaner = new cleaner(ClearChat);
            this.Text = "Checkers";
            Init();
        }

        private void Listener()
        {
            while (_serverSocket.Connected)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8196];
                int bytesRec = _serverSocket.Receive(buffer);
                string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRec);
                if (data.Contains("#updatechat"))
                {
                    UpdateChat(data);
                    continue;
                }
                if (data.Contains("#Updateboard"))
                {
                    UpdateBoardd(data);
                    continue;
                }
                if (data.Contains("#updateTbxClient"))
                {
                    UpdateTbxClient(data);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }





        private void UpdateBoardd(string data)
        {
            string coords = data;
            var reg = new Regex(@"(?<open>\%).*?(?<final-open>\%)");
            var matches = reg.Matches(coords).Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Groups["final"].Value).ToList();
            foreach (string strCoords in matches)
            {
                coords = strCoords;
            }
            string[] subs = coords.Split(',');
            string ast = subs[0];
            string bst = subs[1];
            int a = int.Parse(ast);
            int b = int.Parse(bst);
            foreach (var btn in buttons)
            {
                if ((btn.Location.X == a) && (btn.Location.Y == b))
                {

                    ActionsWithBoard(btn);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Print(string msg)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(Printer, msg);
                return;
            }
            if (ChatBox.Text.Length == 0)
                ChatBox.AppendText(msg);
            else
                ChatBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + msg);
        }

        public void Send(string data)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
                int bytesSent = _serverSocket.Send(buffer);
            }
            catch { Print("Server disconnected"); }
        }
        int CountUsers { get; set; } = 0;



  

        private void enterApp_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Name = tbxUserName.Text;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name)) return;
            ViewFigures();
            Send("#setname&" + Name);
            ChatBox.Enabled = true;
            chat_msg.Enabled = true;
            Chat_Send.Enabled = true;
            tbxUserName.Enabled = false;
            enterApp.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Вот CheckersLogic (тоже не весь)

```
public partial class ClientForm
{
    const int mapSize = 8;
    const int cellSize = 50;
    int currentPlayer;
    int countEatSteps = 0;
    int[,] map = new int[mapSize, mapSize];
    bool isContunue = false;
    bool IsMoving = false;
    Button pressedButton;
    Button prevButton;
    Button[,] buttons = new Button[mapSize, mapSize];
    List<Button> simpleSteps = new List<Button>();
    Image whiteFigure;
    Image blackFigure;
    public void SwitchControls()
    {
        Chat_Send.Enabled = true;
        ChatBox.Enabled = true;
        tbxUserName.Enabled = true;
        enterApp.Enabled = true;
        chat_msg.Enabled = true;
        btnDisc.Enabled = true;
    }
    public void DeactivateButtons()
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < mapSize; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < mapSize; j++)
                {
                    buttons[i, j].Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message + "Error with Deactivate");
        }

    }

    public void ShowDiagonal(int IcurrFigure, int JcurrFigure, bool isOneStep = false)
    {
        int j = JcurrFigure + 1;
        for (int i = IcurrFigure - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (currentPlayer == 1 && isOneStep && !isContunue) break;
            if (IsInsideBorders(i, j))
            {
                if (!DeterminePath(i, j)) // делает поле активным и окрашивает в жёлтый
                    break;
            }
            if (j < 7)
                j++;
            else break;

            if (isOneStep)
                break;
        }

        j = JcurrFigure - 1;
        for (int i = IcurrFigure - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (currentPlayer == 1 && isOneStep && !isContunue) break;
            if (IsInsideBorders(i, j))
            {
                if (!DeterminePath(i, j))
                    break;
            }
            if (j > 0)
                j--;
            else break;

            if (isOneStep)
                break;
        }

        j = JcurrFigure - 1;
        for (int i = IcurrFigure + 1; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if (currentPlayer == 2 && isOneStep && !isContunue) break;
            if (IsInsideBorders(i, j)) // выходит ли за границы доски
            {
                if (!DeterminePath(i, j))
                    break;
            }
            if (j > 0)
                j--;
            else break;

            if (isOneStep)
                break;
        }

        j = JcurrFigure + 1;
        for (int i = IcurrFigure + 1; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if (currentPlayer == 2 && isOneStep && !isContunue) break;
            if (IsInsideBorders(i, j))
            {
                if (!DeterminePath(i, j))
                    break;
            }
            if (j < 7)
                j++;
            else break;

            if (isOneStep)
                break;
        }
    }

    public bool IsButtonHasEatStep(int IcurrFigure, int JcurrFigure, bool isOneStep, int[] dir)
    {
        bool eatStep = false;
        int j = JcurrFigure + 1;
        for (int i = IcurrFigure - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (currentPlayer == 1 && isOneStep && !isContunue) break;
            if (dir[0] == 1 && dir[1] == -1 && !isOneStep) break;
            if (IsInsideBorders(i, j))
            {
                if (map[i, j] != 0 && map[i, j] != currentPlayer)
                {
                    eatStep = true;
                    if (!IsInsideBorders(i - 1, j + 1))
                        eatStep = false;
                    else if (map[i - 1, j + 1] != 0)
                        eatStep = false;
                    else return eatStep;
                }
            }
            if (j < 7)
                j++;
            else break;

            if (isOneStep)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        j = JcurrFigure - 1;
        for (int i = IcurrFigure - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (currentPlayer == 1 && isOneStep && !isContunue) break;
            if (dir[0] == 1 && dir[1] == 1 && !isOneStep) break;
            if (IsInsideBorders(i, j))
            {
                if (map[i, j] != 0 && map[i, j] != currentPlayer)
                {
                    eatStep = true;
                    if (!IsInsideBorders(i - 1, j - 1))
                        eatStep = false;
                    else if (map[i - 1, j - 1] != 0)
                        eatStep = false;
                    else return eatStep;
                }
            }
            if (j > 0)
                j--;
            else break;

            if (isOneStep)
                break;
        }

        j = JcurrFigure - 1;
        for (int i = IcurrFigure + 1; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if (currentPlayer == 2 && isOneStep && !isContunue) break;
            if (dir[0] == -1 && dir[1] == 1 && !isOneStep) break;
            if (IsInsideBorders(i, j))
            {
                if (map[i, j] != 0 && map[i, j] != currentPlayer)
                {
                    eatStep = true;
                    if (!IsInsideBorders(i + 1, j - 1))
                        eatStep = false;
                    else if (map[i + 1, j - 1] != 0)
                        eatStep = false;
                    else return eatStep;
                }
            }
            if (j > 0)
                j--;
            else break;

            if (isOneStep)
                break;
        }

        j = JcurrFigure + 1;
        for (int i = IcurrFigure + 1; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if (currentPlayer == 2 && isOneStep && !isContunue) break;
            if (dir[0] == -1 && dir[1] == -1 && !isOneStep) break;
            if (IsInsideBorders(i, j))
            {
                if (map[i, j] != 0 && map[i, j] != currentPlayer)
                {
                    eatStep = true;
                    if (!IsInsideBorders(i + 1, j + 1))
                        eatStep = false;
                    else if (map[i + 1, j + 1] != 0)
                        eatStep = false;
                    else return eatStep;
                }
            }
            if (j < 7)
                j++;
            else break;

            if (isOneStep)
                break;
        }
        return eatStep;
    }

    private void ActionsWithBoard(Button pressedButton)
    {
        if (prevButton != null)
            prevButton.BackColor = GetPrevButColor(prevButton);
        if (map[pressedButton.Location.Y / cellSize, pressedButton.Location.X / cellSize] != 0 && map[pressedButton.Location.Y / cellSize, pressedButton.Location.X / cellSize] == currentPlayer)
        {
            CloseSteps();
            pressedButton.BackColor = Color.Green;
            DeactivateButtons();
            pressedButton.Enabled = true;
            countEatSteps = 0;
            if (pressedButton.Text == "D")
            {
                ShowSteps(pressedButton.Location.Y / cellSize, pressedButton.Location.X / cellSize, false);
            }
            else
            {
                ShowSteps(pressedButton.Location.Y / cellSize, pressedButton.Location.X / cellSize);
            }
            if (IsMoving)
            {
                CloseSteps();
                pressedButton.BackColor = GetPrevButColor(pressedButton);
                ShowPossibleSteps();
                IsMoving = false;
            }
            else
                IsMoving = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (IsMoving)
            {
                isContunue = false;
                if (Math.Abs(pressedButton.Location.X / cellSize - prevButton.Location.X / cellSize) > 1)
                {
                    isContunue = true;
                    DeleteEaten(pressedButton, prevButton);
                }
                int temp = map[pressedButton.Location.Y / cellSize, pressedButton.Location.X / cellSize];
                map[pressedButton.Location.Y / cellSize, pressedButton.Location.X / cellSize] = map[prevButton.Location.Y / cellSize, prevButton.Location.X / cellSize];
                map[prevButton.Location.Y / cellSize, prevButton.Location.X / cellSize] = temp;
                pressedButton.Image = prevButton.Image;
                prevButton.Image = null;
                pressedButton.Text = prevButton.Text;
                prevButton.Text = "";
                SwitchButtonToCheat(pressedButton);
                countEatSteps = 0;
                IsMoving = false;
                CloseSteps();
                DeactivateButtons();
                if (pressedButton.Text == "D")
                    ShowSteps(pressedButton.Location.Y / cellSize, pressedButton.Location.X / cellSize, false);
                else ShowSteps(pressedButton.Location.Y / cellSize, pressedButton.Location.X / cellSize);
                if (countEatSteps == 0 || !isContunue)
                {
                    CloseSteps();
                    SwitchPlayer();
                    ShowPossibleSteps();
                    isContunue = false;
                }
                else if (isContunue)
                {
                    pressedButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    pressedButton.Enabled = true;
                    IsMoving = true;
                }
            }
        }

        prevButton = pressedButton;
    }
```

Comment: partial - это нормально.

Comment: я бы больше переживал за то, что у тебя логика привязана к юаю. А они должны быть разделены.

Comment: У вас же имеются классы `Printer`, `Cleaner`, которые содержат какой-то код. Создайте новые классы, в который вынесите лишний код из формы. Например, `Sender`, который содержит всю логику по отправке сообщений. А в классе формы будет лишь вызываться его метод `sender.Send(...);`. Напрашивается некий класс `Solver`, в котором содержится логика шашек. И так далее.